# Equivalent definitions of Dual of a variety.

Tags: differential-geometry, algebraic-geometry, projective-geometry

Let $X$ be a closed irreducible projective variety of dimension $n$ in $\mathbb{P}_N.$ The dual of a projective variety is defined in following 2 ways.
Def 1:If $X$ is nonsingular then the dual is the set of all hyperplanes of $\mathbb{P}_N$ which are tangent to $X.$
Def 2: let $A=\{(x,y)\in \mathbb{P}_N\times \mathbb{P}_N^*|x \ is\ nonsingular\ point\ of\ X \ and\ H_y\ is \ tangent \ to\ X\ at\ x\}.$ Here $H_y$ is hyperplane corresponding to $y.$ Take closure of $A$ and define dual to be image of second projection.
How are these two definitions same for nonsingular varieties.
I was reading the duality of projective spaces in the paper topology of complex projective varieties by Klaus Lamotke. The author says these two sets are the same, I dont see how?
Any help is appreciated

Comment: Welcome to Stackexchange. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, *etc.*; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.

Comment: H_y is hyperplane corresponding to y.

Answer (score 1):

The first definition is a bit sloppy. What does it mean for a hyperplane to be tangent to $X$ at a singular point? Do you include all possible hyperplanes through that point? Do you include only ones that are limits of tangent hyperplanes at nearby smooth points? The second definition does precisely the latter.

Consider, for example, the nodal curve $y^2z-x^2(x+z)=0$ in $\Bbb P^2$. What should happen at the origin?

Comment: Thanks. In the first definition i assume $X$ to be nonsingular. I have made the necessary edit.How are they equivalent for nonsingular varieties.

Comment: So my question is basically why for nonsingular variety the set $A$ is closed

Comment: Probably the easiest way to check that is to use the implicit function theorem. Suppose (locally) that $X=\{x\in U\subset\Bbb C^N: f_1=\dots=f_{N-n}=0\}$ with $df_1,\dots,df_{N-n}$ linearly independent on $U$. Then $A$ is given correspondingly by $\{(x,y): f_j=0, y=\sum c_j df_j(x) \text{ for some scalars } c_j\}\subset U\times (\Bbb C^N)^*\}$.

Comment: Could you explain where are you using implicit function theorem?

Comment: Could you please explain why A is given by equations as you mentioned.

Comment: A codimension-$(N-n)$ smooth submanifold is locally cut out by $N-n$ functions with linearly independent derivatives. Perhaps I shouldn't have called it the implicit function theorem, but it's a consequence of the inverse function theorem. The equations I gave are standard linear algebra: If a subspace $V$ is defined as the zero-set of $s$ linearly independent linear functionals, then any linear functional annihilating $V$ is a linear combination of those.